# Cannot change MAC address on notebook

Tags: windows-vista, mac-address, laptop

I've tried to change MAC address on a notebook Toshiba Satellite A200-14E Windows Vista  without success. I've tried to change it via Network settings - Adapter settings.
I've set Network address property for ethernet adapter, but `ipconfig /all` still shows another address even after reboot.

Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you trying to change the MAC and are you sure this is what you are trying to do, not the IP? Network address says to me it's the IP not the MAC.

Comment: @tombull89: You missed the _Adapter settings_ part. Most NIC drivers offer a list of tunable settings, including the hardware address, in the property page of the device itself.

Comment: @Andrey: Have you entered a valid address? AFAIK, any separators such as `-` or `:` are _not_ allowed there.

Comment: No, there is no - and : in the address.

Comment: @grawity, indeed I did. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

Not every NIC does support changing the MAC. In theory, it should be immutable and worldwide unique. Why do you want to do it in the first place?

Comment: The address can be changed as long as the software (NIC driver) generates the Ethernet frames (which I believe it _does_ on today's PCs; not sure).

Comment: As for "in theory"... It remains theory [way](http://mailman.nanog.org/pipermail/nanog/2010-April/020639.html) [too](http://mailman.nanog.org/pipermail/nanog/2010-April/020642.html) [often.](http://mailman.nanog.org/pipermail/nanog/2010-April/020667.html)

Comment: Ah this was to be expected, I guess, especially when NIC's got crappy mass products. This appears to be the only "legal" reason for me though to change your NIC's mac, with only shady "get around access controls" applications left otherwise.

Comment: I want to connect this notebook to the internet but internet account is registered to another MAC.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you look up your wireless NIC. On google. My wireless NIC requres a certain formula to get it to work with a MAC address swap:

0a:23:xx:xx:xx:xx

yours may also. Just google something like:

"XXXXXX MAC address change"

or something of the sort.